# Find words in a string that contains numbers with regex

Tags: regex

I want to find words in a big string that contains numbers, like this

```
a1 or abc3d abc
```

I want `a1`, `abc3d` only

How should I write my regex?

Comment: Try: `\b\w*\d\w*\b`

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I need!

Comment: This is true only when the string contains a single digit.

Comment: @TonyR No, it will match multiple digits as well because `\w` matches any alphanumeric character or underscore. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImQ7f8/1).

Comment: This not what I meant (I was too imprecise), rather it is too general - it also matches 123, for example. It would be better to use [a-z]